Docker's content addressable layers and sha256 digests
Context around this question is - I'm trying to make some calculations on how much of each image is being pulled, on average, when an older version already exists on an instance, for some network statistics.
Note, I have done my best to read and understand the "Explaining Docker Image IDs" blog post by Nigel Brown, and have also looked around a little using the dive tool, though there may be holes in my understanding which is what I'm trying to figure out here.
So, basically I pull image:latest-n-1 and image:latest in that order, where the former is the version of the image that was deployed before the latter. As expected, I see that some layers already exist when I pull image:latest:
8a9c853c85e5: Already exists
9ff1b812780a: Already exists
c33afb4b263f: Already exists
e6b8313e3004: Already exists
77746309ca6c: Already exists
2f4b5489940a: Already exists
b1e5062b6c22: Pull complete
cea4ebb7de8b: Pull complete
254f8aed4d2c: Pull complete
d78389bbd084: Pull complete
7e329668008d: Pull complete
d484bc805e46: Pull complete
b387fe18f313: Pull complete
e493d7350be2: Pull complete
96601556a02d: Pull complete
5af9376a34ac: Pull complete
9512c3f27883: Pull complete
27fb236d8c80: Pull complete
5092bc02bf4d: Pull complete
e15ec5e318c3: Pull complete
db7bc472863d: Pull complete
1c9f52fbb429: Pull complete
95114cf4fd67: Pull complete

My understanding of how this all works after reading that blog post is, each sha is generated based on a layer's contents. And so if I do docker inspect repo/image:tag | jq '.[0].RootFS.Layers' for each image, and given that some layers already exist, I would expect that there is some overlap between the two images. Instead, each image appears to have a completely different set of sha256 digests (I ran a comm -12 ... on the two outputs).
Am I missing something? If two images have common layers, and you can see that through the layers already existing when you pull the newer image, should those common layers not have the same digests? And if they don't have the same digests, how does Docker know that the layer already exists, and not to re-pull it?
Also, how does one match the 12-char string (output during the docker pull) with the sha256 digest? The 12-char string doesn't appear to be a truncation of the full 64-char hex string.
